# How to use Micronaut PropertySource to map data from json file to properties when application starts

Tags: json, yaml, micronaut

I am new to Micronaut and want to know how we can read the properties from json file when application starts. I had some reference code with Spring boot one but not helpful to micronaut.

Here is my secrets.json file:

> ```
> {    
> "dbusername":"testuser",    
> "dbpassword": "testpass" 
> }
> ```

Here is my application.yaml file:

> ```
> mongodb:       
>   uri: mongodb://${dbusername}:${dbpassword}@localhost:27117
>
> secrets:
>   filePath: file:////Users/aaaa/Downloads/secrets.json
> ```

Here is my main application:

```
object TestApplication {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        Micronaut.build()
            .packages("com.test")
            .mainClass(TestApplication.javaClass)
            .start()
    }
}
```

I want to read the secrets from json file and map it to property in yaml file. I heard few things about propertySource but not sure how to use it.

Any quick help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your application you need to inject the path from your `application.yml` and the use Jacksons `ObjectMapper` to parse the JSON file and create a Java instance.

```java
@Singleton
public class SomeClass {
   
   @Value("${secrets.filePath}")
   private File verySecretFile;
   @Inject
   ObjectMapper objectMapper;

   void someMethod() {
     YourClass yourClass = objectMapper.readValue(this.verySecretFile, YourClass.class);
   }
}
```